# Sanitize user input in bash for security purposes

Tags: bash, input, sanitize

How do I sanitise user input in a bash script so that I can then pass it as an argument to another shell program? I want to prevent the following:

```
INPUT="filename;rm -rf /"
ls $INPUT
```

I was thinking it should be enough to surround the user input in double quotes like so:

```
ls "$INPUT"
```

but what if there is a double quote in `$INPUT`?

Or does bash already deal with this problem?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### The Short

Bash already deals with that. Quoting it is sufficient.

```
ls "$INPUT"
```

### The Long

A rough guide to how the shell parses this line is:

```
"ls \"$INPUT\""                     # Raw command line.
["ls", "\"$INPUT\""]                # Break into words.
["ls", "\"filename; rm -rf /\""]    # Perform variable expansion.
["ls", "\"filename; rm -rf /\""]    # Perform word splitting (no change).
["ls", "filename; rm -rf /"]        # Remove quotes.
```

Because of the quotes the `$INPUT` variable does not undergo word splitting. The `ls` will look for a file named `filename; rm -rf /`.

If you didn't quote it then the expansion would proceed differently:

```
"ls $INPUT"                             # Raw command line.
["ls", "$INPUT"]                        # Break into words.
["ls", "filename; rm -rf /"]            # Perform variable expansion.
["ls", "filename;", "rm", "-rf", "/"]   # Perform word splitting.
```

You can at least have consolation that this won't actually execute `rm -rf /`. Rather, it'll pass each of those strings as a file name to `ls`. You'll `ls` some files you didn't intend but at least it won't accidentally execute unwanted commands.

```
jkugelman$ VAR='.; echo hi'
jkugelman$ ls $VAR
ls: .;: No such file or directory
ls: echo: No such file or directory
ls: hi: No such file or directory
```

Excerpts from "man bash":

> #### QUOTING
>
> Quoting  is  used to remove the special meaning of certain characters or words to the shell.  Quoting        can be used to disable special treatment for special characters, to prevent reserved words from being        recognized as such, and to prevent parameter expansion.
>
> #### EXPANSION
>
> Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into words.  There are seven kinds
>          of  expansion  performed: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command
>          substitution, arithmetic expansion, word splitting, and pathname expansion.
>
> Only brace expansion, word splitting, and pathname expansion can change the number of  words  of  the
>          expansion;  other  expansions expand a single word to a single word.  The only exceptions to this are
>          the expansions of `"$@"` and `"${name[@]}"` as explained above (see PARAMETERS).
>
> #### Word Splitting
>
> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution,  and  arithmetic  expansion
>          that did not occur within double quotes for word splitting.
>
> #### Quote Removal
>
> After the preceding expansions, all unquoted occurrences of the characters `\`, `'`, and `"` that  did  not
>          result from one of the above expansions are removed.

Comment: Good call, with the one caveat that this does not apply to `eval`

Comment: Note that bash before 4.0 performed globbing (though not splitting) upon tilde expansion, and there was no way to avoid that except by using a temp variable (or disable globbing altogether with `set -f`).

Comment: Also note that generally speaking, you should do `ls -- "$INPUT"` or `ls -d -- "$INPUT"` if you don't intend to list the content of directories.

Comment: I know, old posting, but - `eval` is an important case.  The "rm" command would get executed if they did `eval ls $INPUT`.  If eval is involved then backquote and `$(cmd)` subexpressions are also possible threats.