# How to use the system() function with user input c++

Tags: c++, console, ping

Sorry for another misleading title, found it hard to describe what it is.  I am trying to have the user be able to type something in the console and have it add that to the end of a system() command. For example:

```
cout << "Input an ip in the form of xx(x).xx(x).xx(x).xx(x)" << endl;
cin >> ipstring;
system("ping");
```

Then have ipstring after ping so they user can type in what they want to ping.  In java I think it would be something like:

```
system( "ping" + ipstring )
```

Comment: Be careful with this.  What if `ipstring` is `; rm -rf /`?

Comment: I accidentaly wiped out my VM disk just a couple of months ago working with some legacy code that heavily used `system`. Seriously do not do that.

Answer (score 1):

`system()` expects a `char*` as input.

Assuming `ipstring` is a `std::string`, you can do this:

```
system( ("ping " + ipstring).c_str() );
```

If not, you could use something more like this instead:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "ping " << ipstring;
system( oss.str().c_str() );
```

That being said, you really should not use `system()` for this.  As others have stated, it is an injection attack vector.  You should instead use a native API for performing the ping, when available, such as [`IcmpSendEcho()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366050.aspx) on Windows.  Or a third-party library.

Comment: You can use `system` as long as you [sanitize user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273074/sanitize-user-input-in-bash-for-security-purposes) first.

Comment: Agreed.  On the other hand, `system()` is spawning a separate process, which may not always be desirable.  If there is an API function available to perform the same task, you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it's almost exactly the same thing, assuming `ipstring` is an `std::string`:

```
system(("ping"+ipstring).c_str());
```

If `ipstring` is a `const char*`, then you should convert ping to a `std::string` first:

```
system((std::string("ping")+ipstring).c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'sprintf', like so

```
char to_send[1000];
sprintf(to_send,"ping %s" , ipstring.c_str());
system(to_send)
```

Assuming your 'ipstring' is an std::string.